# GeeksForGeeks: Alien dictionary C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, depth-first-search, topological-sorting

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-sorted-dictionary-find-precedence-characters/

please review for performance, the adjacency list is the problematic part for me.

> Given a sorted dictionary (array of words) of an alien language, find
>   order of characters in the language. Examples:
>
> Input:  words[] = {"baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"} Output: Order
>   of characters is 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c' Note that words are sorted and in
>   the given language "baa"  comes before "abcd", therefore 'b' is before
>   'a' in output. Similarly we can find other orders.
>
> Input:  words[] = {"caa", "aaa", "aab"} Output: Order of characters is
>   'c', 'a', 'b'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace GraphsQuestions.Properties
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-sorted-dictionary-find-precedence-characters/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class AlienDictionaryTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTest1()
        {
            string[] words = {"baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"};
            int numOfChars = 4;
            var expected = new List<char>{'b', 'd', 'a', 'c'};
            Solution solution = new Solution(numOfChars, words);
            List<char> res = solution.Sort();
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected,res );
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTest2()
        {
            string[] words = { "caa", "aaa", "aab" };
            int numOfChars = 3;
            var expected = new List<char> { 'c','a','b' };
            Solution solution = new Solution(numOfChars, words);
            List<char> res = solution.Sort();
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }
    }

    public class Solution
    {
        private Graph _graph;
        public Solution(int numOfChars, string[] words)
        {
            _graph = new Graph(numOfChars);
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length-1; i++)
            {
                string word1 = words[i];
                string word2 = words[i + 1];
                for (int j = 0; j < Math.Min(word1.Length, word2.Length); j++)
                {
                    if (word1[j] != word2[j])
                    {
                        _graph.AddEdge(word1[j] - 'a', word2[j] - 'a');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public List<char> Sort()
        {
            return _graph.TopologicalSort();
        }

    }

    public class Graph
    {
        private List<List<int>> _adjList;
        // for each letter we create a vertex
        public Graph(int numOfchars)
        {
            _adjList = new List<List<int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfchars; i++)
            {
                _adjList.Add(new List<int>());
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// run through the entire adj list
        /// and run DFS from each node to their neighbors
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<char> TopologicalSort()
        {
            var stack = new Stack<int>();
            bool[] visited = new bool[_adjList.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < _adjList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!visited[i])
                {
                    DFS(i, visited, stack);
                }
            }

            var res = new List<char>();
            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                res.Add((char)(stack.Pop() +'a'));
            }

            return res;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// mark the current node as visited and recurs to the adj nodes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <param name="visited"></param>
        /// <param name="stack"></param>
        private void DFS(int index, bool[] visited, Stack<int> stack)
        {
            visited[index] = true;
            foreach (var node in _adjList[index])
            {
                if (!visited[node])
                {
                    DFS(node, visited, stack);
                }
            }
            stack.Push(index);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// add an edge between char1 to char2
        ///  this will mark the adj between them
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="char1"></param>
        /// <param name="char2"></param>
        public void AddEdge(int char1, int char2)
        {
            _adjList[char1].Add(char2);
        }
    }
}
```